# How to hide tags and categories from a single product page woocommerce ? Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, categories

I have been trying to hide the tags and categories from (display only) on my single product page, the developer of my theme sent me the following code, to be added in the customize css section but it is not working.

```
.wcs-meta__cat, .wcs-meta__tags {
    display:none !important
}
```

I have also read that these tags help you in SEO of your website, what if i just want to hide them in the frontend but they stay in the backend, is it easily possible?

This is the link of the product page:https://www.hodst.com/wp/product/p-a-n-i-s-y-n-t-h-w-a-v-e/#

Answer (score 1):

```
/**

 *        Hide SKU, Cats, Tags @ Single Product Page - WooCommerce

*/

 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

Need place above code in theme's function.php file accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much Akber, i'll check it out.